# Make Two Dynamically Filled Tables the Same Height

Tags: css, vb.net

I have two tables that are side-by-side on my form.  I'm filling the tables with two sql queries of the same data table.  It is entirely possible that the two queries will return a different number of results.  If I just let the tables size on their own, their vertical centers are aligned, and the height of each seems to be the minimum required to show the data for that query.  This looks pretty strange in the context of the rest of my form.

[image]
What I would like is for the smaller table to grow to be the same height as the taller table.  The content of the smaller table should be top justified, with just blank space added below it to make it the same size as the larger.

[image]

I'm not very familiar with CSS, so I tried doing it in my vb code, with

```
Dim Height as String = Math.Max(Convert.ToInt16(table1.Height),Convert.ToInt16(table2.Height))
table1.Height = Height
table2.Height = Height
```

after I filled my tables, but I get an error for 'Input string was not in a correct format'.  If I debug, the `Height` property is blank for my tables at this point, which is probably what is causing the error.

Is there a way I can force my two tables to be the same height?  Do I just need to move my code?  Or will that code never work?  Or is this something that needs to be handled in CSS?

Comment: A fiddle/codepen of this occurring would be extremely helpful.

Comment: This is something that _should_ be handled in CSS. Could you post the generated HTML (not all of it, just the necessary bits).

Comment: If you know the number of records returned(which you should be able to retrieve from the reader) you can check and see which table returns the most results and then set the height of each table to a multiple of that table's results. So if table A is 20 rows(and assumed max), and your cell height is 20px, make the table height `table1.Height = 20 x 20` and poof... you got it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont do vb but the result you are trying to achieve can be done programatically ( I used javascript).

The idea behind the code is to find out (dynamically ofcourse) the height of the tables after they are populated and then based of the comparison of heights, the larger height is given to the smaller table. Also keep in mind that the result has to be converted into number for comparison and when finally the bigger value is found and applied, add the "px" to the value.

Here is a code snippet...

```js
document.getElementById("tbl1h").innerHTML = "tbl1 height: " + document.getElementById("tbl1").offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("tbl2h").innerHTML = "tbl2 height: " + document.getElementById("tbl2").offsetHeight;

if (Number(document.getElementById("tbl1").offsetHeight) >= Number(document.getElementById("tbl2").offsetHeight)) {
    document.getElementById("tbl2").style.height = Number(document.getElementById("tbl1").offsetHeight)+"px";
} else {
    document.getElementById("tbl1").style.height = Number(document.getElementById("tbl2").offsetHeight)+"px";
}
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = " After change:: tbl1 height: " + document.getElementById("tbl1").offsetHeight + "  tbl2 height: " + document.getElementById("tbl2").offsetHeight;
```

```css
table,th,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  align: center;
}
th {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#tbl1 {
  width: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
}
#tbl2 {
  width: 70%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl1" class="tbl">
    <tr>
        <th>blah</th>
        <th>77666</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>asasaas</td>
        <td>grfrrrgrrt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>asasaas</td>
        <td>grfrrrgrrt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>asasaas</td>
        <td>grfrrrgrrt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>asasaas</td>
        <td>grfrrrgrrt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>asasaas</td>
        <td>grfrrrgrrt</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="tbl2" class="tbl">
    <tr>
        <th>wooohooooo</th>
        <th>ahaaa</th>
        <th>rtrt</th>
        <th>aas</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>nnnsnnsnsnn</td>
        <td>aasqs</td>
        <td>ndcd</td>
        <td>776676676</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>nnnsnnsnsnn</td>
        <td>aasqs</td>
        <td>ndcd</td>
        <td>776676676</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>nnnsnnsnsnn</td>
        <td>aasqs</td>
        <td>ndcd</td>
        <td>776676676</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>nnnsnnsnsnn</td>
        <td>aasqs</td>
        <td>ndcd</td>
        <td>776676676</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>nnnsnnsnsnn</td>
        <td>aasqs</td>
        <td>ndcd</td>
        <td>776676676</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>nnnsnnsnsnn</td>
        <td>aasqs</td>
        <td>ndcd</td>
        <td>776676676</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>nnnsnnsnsnn</td>
        <td>aasqs</td>
        <td>ndcd</td>
        <td>776676676</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>nnnsnnsnsnn</td>
        <td>aasqs</td>
        <td>ndcd</td>
        <td>776676676</td>
    </tr>
</table>
Before change:::
<div id="tbl1h"></div>
<div id="tbl2h"></div>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Hope this is what you were looking for. Good luck

Update:: Here is a fiddle link as well http://jsfiddle.net/fe2crmsx/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was trying to explain in my comment on your post...

```
    Dim rows1 As Integer = 20 'This would be assigned the rows returned by your sqldatareader
    Dim rows2 As Integer = 10 'Same as before but for second table's query
    Dim rowHeight As Integer = 20
    Dim getHeight As Integer

    If rows1 > rows2 Then
        getHeight = rows1 * rowHeight
    Else
        getHeight = rows2 * rowHeight
    End If

    table1.Height = getHeight
    table2.Height = getHeight
```